# Learning Ajax: Dynamic content not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm starting to learn Ajax for a project but I got some problems... This is my situation so far:

1- I have a navbar with different buttons to show content.

2- I have a div container where goes the selected content.

3- When clicked the desired content it never ends loading.

```js
$(function(){

    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });
  
    var ajax_load = "<img width='50px' src='https://berkeleyloop.ridecell.com/static/common/images/loading-circle.gif'/>";
    
    var loadUrl1 = "http://fullhdpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Beautiful-Pagani-Zonda-Wallpapers.jpg";
    $("#load1").click(function(){
        $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl1);
    });
    
    var loadUrl2 = "http://fullhdpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Most-Beautiful-Pagani-Zonda-Wallpapers.jpg";
    $("#load2").click(function(){
        $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl2);
    });  
  
});
```

```css
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 48px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #181818;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#result {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px; 
  width: calc(100% - 48px); 
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="navbar">
  <button id="load1">1</button>
  <button id="load2">2</button>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

What did I missed? Please help me to achieve the desired effect!

Comment: What do you mean by "never ends loading"? `<img>` element  replaced by results from `.load()`?

Comment: Firstly, Wordpress has it's own way of handling ajax. Secondly, you don't need ajax at all for images, just insert them in the DOM, and they will load all by themselves.

Comment: you are loading image on click event of buttons and image is loading in your desired location so what else you wants to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't load content from different web site by using load. to do that you has to be rights. if you check your console you will see this

"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'"

edit:
i think this will help

codepen.io/airsakarya/pen/zqLVZo?editors=1010

Comment: Yes! Thank You! :)

Comment: @Ismail  You should copy the details of your answer to your post in case the link you reference goes away.